# screen DPI - is there and equivalent command/action to Windows 150% Display

Tags: virtualbox, display, resolution, screen, dpi

I have a wide screen of high resolution and I see everything small on it. So In windows I set the display to 150%, I would like to do something similar in Ubuntu. Simply changing screen resolution to lower resolution doesn't help because Ubuntu is in a virtual machine and it simply changes the VM window to the actual resolution.
Is there a command or a simple hack that can do the trick?

EDIT: I am running Ubuntu as a VirtualBox VM on Windows 7 host.

Comment: This can be achieved easily uising **Ubuntu Tweak** (Tweak >> fonts, and Tweaks >> Unity).  Or do you want to configure the settings at command line, or using a configuration editor?

Comment: It is a basic installation of Ubuntu, just to make a base machine for later cloning. I'd rather not use any third party tools for now. Command line sounds good but I have no idea what command to do or what file to edit. I looked up the xorg configuration file, but it doesn't exist anymore,  and I really want to close this machine and clone it already...

Comment: Confirm **Ubuntu** version.  And, you don't want to install ***Ubuntu Tweak***?

Comment: 12.04 and what part of NO THIRD PARTY TOOLS didn't I explain correctly? NO THIRD PARTY TOOLS means no, I do not want to install Ubuntu tweak or any other tool that does not come with Ubuntu or available for download from Ubuntu's official repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install "Advanced settings" from the Software Center.  This will at least allow you to change the font size.  There is no dpi setting in Ubuntu AFAIK.

Comment: I guess there is no. I believe it is important in an era of HD, but perhaps it is up to unity/Gnome to make..

Answer (score 1):

If your virtual machine software allows it you may be able to adjust the screen size of the virtual machine window within the host computer--this works for me when I use kvm natively.

With virt-manager I must first select the View->Scale Display->Always option for the virt-manager machine window.

It may be helpful to mention what you are using to run your Ubuntu virtual machine and add a tag for that (both in your question).

Comment: You are right. Will do.

Comment: BTW, as I edited, it's VB, and AFAIK there is no way to adjust the display to window size. But maybe you can prove me wrong? hopefully?